# Dynamic change of binded visibility of flipview's item template

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visibility, xbind

I am making UWP desktop app using c# and xaml.

I need to change visibility of two text blocks(let's say **TextBlock1** and **TextBlock2**) which is a part of FlipView's item template, depending on user input (pressing button).

If button is pressed first time **TextBlock1** is **visible** and **TextBlock2** is **hidden (or collapsed)**

Now If button is pressed second time **TextBlock1** would be **collapsed** and **TextBlock2** would be **visible**.

Then "cycle" repeats and it is going from beginning (see code)

Item source is list of classes `List<SourceClass> SourceClassList`

*Source class* has two members which type is Visibility (one member is binded to TextBlock1 and second to TextBlock2)

In Page class it is working visibility of each member changes as I described

But the change is only visible if I navigate away from page and than came back but as I mentioned I want it to changes dynamically

I was trying OneWay and TwoWay of binding mode but none of them works

**MainPage.xaml**

```
                 <FlipView x:Name="Cards" ItemsSource="{x:Bind SourceClassList, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:SourceClass" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="{x:Bind FrontSideOfCard }" Visibility="{x:Bind visibilityOfFrontSide }" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" Text="{x:Bind BackSideOfCard}" Visibility="{x:Bind visibilityOfBackSide}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </FlipView>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    public List<SourceClass> SourceClassList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        IsTextBlock1Visible = false;
        SourceClassList = //here is import from previous class which is not important for the problem 
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }                                                                             
    private void Flip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsTextBlock1Visible == false)
        {
            SourceClassList[cards.SelectedItem].visibilityOfBackSide = Visibility.Visible;
           SourceClassList[cards.SelectedItem].visibilityOfFrontSide = Visibility.Collapsed;
            IsTextBlock1Visibl = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SourceClassList[cards.SelectedItem].visibilityOfBackSide = Visibility.Collapsed;
           SourceClassList[cards.SelectedItem].visibilityOfFrontSide = Visibility.Visible;
            IsTextBlock1Visibl = false;
        }
    }
```

**SourceClass.cs**

```
public string TextBlock1 { get; set; }
public string TextBlock2 { get; set; }

public Visibility visibilityOfFrontSide { get; set; }
public Visibility visibilityOfBackSide { get; set; }

public SourceClass(string txt1, string txt2)
{
    TextBlock1 = txt1;
    TextBlock2 = txt2;
    
    visibilityOfBackSide = Visibility.Collapsed;
    visibilityOfFrontSide = Visibility.Visible;
    
}
```

PS: binding in general works as expected

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying OneWay and TwoWay of binding mode but none of them works

The problem is that you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for SourceClass `visibilityOfFrontSide` and `visibilityOfBackSide` property. it will cause property value update does not response UI. Please update SourceClass like the following. And set `Visibility` binding model as one way (default is onetime for x:bind)

**`SourceClass`**

```
public class SourceClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TextBlock1 { get; set; }
    public string TextBlock2 { get; set; }

    private Visibility _visibilityOfFrontSide;
    private Visibility _visibilityOfBackSide;
    public Visibility visibilityOfFrontSide
    {
        get
        {
            return _visibilityOfFrontSide;
        }
        set
        {
            _visibilityOfFrontSide = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Visibility visibilityOfBackSide
    {
        get { return _visibilityOfBackSide; }
        set
        {
            _visibilityOfBackSide = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SourceClass(string txt1, string txt2)
    {
        TextBlock1 = txt1;
        TextBlock2 = txt2;

        visibilityOfBackSide = Visibility.Collapsed;
        visibilityOfFrontSide = Visibility.Visible;

    }
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Xaml**

```
 <StackPanel>
     <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" Text="{x:Bind TextBlock1 }" Visibility="{x:Bind visibilityOfFrontSide,Mode=OneWay}" />
     <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" Text="{x:Bind TextBlock2}" Visibility="{x:Bind visibilityOfBackSide,Mode=OneWay}"/>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: For everyone else to gain access to [CallerMemberName] use namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices. Nico, thank you very much